# Adding items to ArrayList with separation

Tags: java, arraylist, web-scraping, data-modeling

I'm doing a project on web scraping using ArrayLists. When I scrape the info, it comes back as `item [0] = pencil`, `item [1] = $1.50`.  I would like these items to be together, or if possible it would be even better if the prices and item each had their own id, but each was somehow linked together so that I could reference each one separately.  Also, sometimes when scraping I get `item [2] = paper`, `item [3] = $5.00`, `item [4] = wide bound college ruled`, where `item [4]` represents an optional description that was included with the item that would need to be included in the ArrayList or in a separate ArrayList linked by ids as before. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Why not use HashMap with item that has id and description, and value is the price ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the name and the price, your best solution is to use a Map, works kind of like an ArrayList<T>, but instead of a single element you have a couple <Key,Value>, like <pencil, 1,50>.
If you need more than two values I would suggest to create your own class, for example:

```
   public class Item {
       private String name;
       private double price;
       private String description;
   }
```

With all the extra methods you need, then declare your ArrayList like this;

```
 ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>()
```

Comment: Well the main problem I'm having is that when I scrape the info using jsoup, the document that comes back looks like this: `Pencil $1.50  Ruler $3.00  Paper $5.00 Wide bound college ruled`, with no separation of items other than spaces. I need the items to come back as they are, otherwise I won't know which prices and descriptions correspond to which items. To add them to a map, it's looking like I'll need to add each value manually, since some items have a description and some don't, and there's too many items on the page to do it that way, unless I'm just missing something.

Comment: For instance `item[0] = Pencil, item [1] = $1.50, item [2] = Ruler, item [3] = $3.00, item [4] = Paper, item [5] = $5.00, item [6] = Wide bound college ruled`. I'm not sure how I could take this list and make sure that each item was put in it's appropriate category without ending up with the description being put in the `name` variable or vice versa.

Comment: I think I am missing something (and by now you probably have a solution), but you might want to look for differences from the name and the description. Let's say, for example, that when the name is in item[n],  you know that the element [n+1] is surely a price. Or, from what I can see, names always starts with capital letters maybe. I can't see any easier solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to make a class Item width variables for your name, price and description.

Then you can make an ArrayList to store all of your items.

Answer (score 1):

You should model the object as a class, for example "item", and add each value as a variable of the class. For example:

```
public class item{

    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String description; //If there's no description it could be null

    // Constructor
    ...

    // Getters and setters
   ...
}
```

You will need to format the price as a double.

Comment: Once I create the class `item` How could i take the list `Pencil $1.50 Ruler $3.00 Paper $5.00 Wide bound college ruled` that is returned from web scraping and ensure that `wide bound college ruled` ends up being set for the variable `description`? The page that I am scraping contains hundreds of patterns like this where there is an optional description thrown in, therefore I would need the setter to be able to recognize what is and what isn't a 'name' variable somehow.